# Regex working in application but not in Regex101

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use the below regex in my JS that is already working on a "phone number" form field in my company's application.

When I attempt to put it into Regex101's playground and type in 777-777-7777 I cannot get a match. It makes no sense. Anyone know what the issue can be? I am just trying to gain a better understanding of regular expressions as a junior developer.

```
[2-9]\\d{2}(-){0,1}[2-9]\\d{2}(-){0,1}\\d{4}$
```

Comment: If you read regex 101's description of your regex (over on the right side), you would see that it says *\\ matches the character \ literally*. By the way, `{0,1}` can be written as `?`. Also, don't you want to anchor this at the beginning with `^`?

Comment: Thanks. That is awesome. Just added the ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript regex, you must escape the backslashes (`\`), so your regex looks like `[2-9]\\d{2}(-){0,1}[2-9]\\d{2}(-){0,1}\\d{4}$`.

But for Regex101, you must unescape them, so your regex is `[2-9]\d{2}(-){0,1}[2-9]\d{2}(-){0,1}\d{4}$`

As a sidenote: do you really mean to capture the `-`?

Comment: You only need to escape it, if the regex is defined as a string in JavaScript. JavaScript has a regex notation, where you don't need to escape it: `var regex = /regex/;`

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 yes, forgot to mention that. considering that the OP escaped the backslashes, it was implicit that he was using string.

Comment: I sure was! 

pattern: { message: "Invalid", params: "[2-9]\\d{2}(-){0,1}[2-9]\\d{2}(-){0,1}\\d{4}$"} });

Comment: Oh, and @BrunoFerreira, is there no reason to capture "-" ?

Comment: it depends on your following code. if you are using only for validation of a string format, then no